# Problem with Prestashop frontend - how to optimize my code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, prestashop

I have a problem with my code that I use for item descriptions in my Prestashop store. The point is that when I add a description in html to the store, I do not provide the "ALT" attribute of the photo. I have scripts that do this automatically.

Here is the html code that I add to the full description of the item:

```
<img class="img" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/547/596/original/hearts-icons-vectors-illustrations.jpg" width="200" height="300">
```

After saving the changes, the code displayed in the browser looks like this:

```
<img class="img" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/547/596/original/hearts-icons-vectors-illustrations.jpg" alt="hearts icons vectors illustrations" width="200" height="300"><p class="alt">hearts-icons-vectors-illustrations.jpg</p>
```

The second part of the code that was added by the script is used to display the name of the photo when hovering over it.

And here is the problem. The point is that the script adds the same data that another script adds to the "ALT" of the photo. Without **"-"** and **".jpg"** characters.

JS and CSS files are in the theme folder: **"custom css"** and **"custom JS"**

Here is the full code that I am using in my Prestashop store:

```js
$(".img").wrap('<div class="alt-wrap"/>');
$(".img").each(function () {
  $(this).after('<p class="alt">' + $(this).attr("alt") + "</p>");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("img").each(function () {
    var $img = $(this);
    var filename = $img.attr("src");
    if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {
      var altText = filename.substring(
        filename.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
        filename.lastIndexOf(".")
      );
      altText = altText.replace("-", " ").replace(".jpg", "");
      $img.attr("alt", altText);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.img2 { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0px;
    column-count: max-width;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .img-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .img { 
    display: block; 
}

    .alt-wrap { 
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px;
      color: whitesmoke;
      border: 5px solid transparent;
     border-image:   linear-gradient(to right, green 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%,red 50%, red 75%, magenta 75%) 5;
    }

    .alt-wrap p.alt {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 22px;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all 10ms linear;
      transition-delay: 300ms;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .alt-wrap:hover > p.alt { 
      opacity: 1; 
      transition-delay: 0s;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 900;
      color: white;
      font-size: 150%;
      border: 20px solid transparent;
      margin-left: 1%;
      margin-right: 1%;
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img2"><div class="img-wrap"><img class="img" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/547/596/original/hearts-icons-vectors-illustrations.jpg" width="200" height="300">
```

How can I change/optimize the above codes so that the name of the photo is displayed without the "-" and ".jpg" signs after hovering the mouse cursor?

Here on hover it shows "undefined" on my website it shows "hearts-icons-vectors-illustrations.jpg" I want it to show without "-" and ".jpg".

Prestashop version 1.7.7.3.

Comment: when adding it in p you can use text.slice(0, -4); it will remove last 4 character from string which is in your case  .jpg

Comment: while assigning value  you can use this str.replace(/-/g, " ").slice(0,-4); it will replace - sign into space and remove last 4 character which will be .jpg

Comment: Where exactly should I put this code?

Answer (score 0):

it's showing undefined that's why i am doing it by adding innerHTML
$(".alt").html(altText.replace(/-/g, " "));
I just added this line in your code it will replace all - with space so output will be what you want "hearts icons vectors illustrations"

```js
$(".img").wrap('<div class="alt-wrap"/>');
$(".img").each(function () {
  $(this).after('<p class="alt">' + $(this).attr("alt") + "</p>");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("img").each(function () {
    var $img = $(this);
    var filename = $img.attr("src");
    let text = filename
    if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {
      var altText = filename.substring(
        filename.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
        filename.lastIndexOf(".")
      );
      altText = altText.replace("-", " ").replace(".jpg", "");
      $img.attr("alt", altText);
      // it's showing undefined that's why i am doing it by adding innerHTML 
      $(this).next().html(altText.replace(/-/g, " "));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.img2 { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0px;
    column-count: max-width;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .img-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .img { 
    display: block; 
}

    .alt-wrap { 
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px;
      color: whitesmoke;
      border: 5px solid transparent;
     border-image:   linear-gradient(to right, green 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%,red 50%, red 75%, magenta 75%) 5;
    }

    .alt-wrap p.alt {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 22px;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all 10ms linear;
      transition-delay: 300ms;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .alt-wrap:hover > p.alt { 
      opacity: 1; 
      transition-delay: 0s;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 900;
      color: white;
      font-size: 150%;
      border: 20px solid transparent;
      margin-left: 1%;
      margin-right: 1%;
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img2"><div class="img-wrap"><img class="img" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/547/596/original/hearts-icons-vectors-illustrations.jpg" width="200" height="300">
```

Comment: Here it works perfectly, but after adding the code to the store's website, it displays the "alt" on each photo the same and not at all compatible with the "alt" of the photo :(

Comment: I updated my code snippet try to add this    $(this).next().html(altText.replace(/-/g, " ")); I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Now it works as it should!!! Thank you :) I don't know how to repay you :)

Comment: And how to limit the operation of this script to a specific DIV?

Comment: The point is that it also changes the descriptions not only in the photos from the item description but also in other places on the page.

Comment: $("img").each(function () this is selecting all images on your page give specific class to the  images where you want this effect then here $("img").each(function () insted of $("img") use that sepecific class.

Comment: Once again your help is invaluable :)